# CSS box shadow not working in IE7/8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hey all i am trying to figure out how to make the box shadow work in IE 7 or 8. It currenty works fine in IE9 and all the other browsers.

Here is my CSS code:

```
#main{
    -moz-box-shadow:#000 0px 0px 40px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:#000 0px 0px 40px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #000;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity: 0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
    behavior: url(ie-css3.htc); 
}
```

In IE8:
[image: ie8]

In IE9:
[image: IE9]

Any help would be great!

Comment: It's not supported in IE7/8 - http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need to use a shadow filter to emulate this in Internet Explorer 7 and 8:

Source: http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow

MSDN documentation of the "shadow" filter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533086(v=vs.85).aspx